# Extract dynamic data to clipboard with iMacros

Tags: html, web-scraping, imacros

I want to extract dynamic word from a line of sentence. It is OTP.
Problem is the OTP changes in every refresh & this 6 character OTP lies in a text line.

e.g: Generated OTP for application id is : 30AF06. (This OTP is valid for 5 min.). This "30AF06" is need to be extracted from this line.

Here is the html body part:

```
<tr>
 <td valign="top" width="100%">
    <table class="visa_table" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
             <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold"><br>Generated OTP for application id is : 30AF06.  (This OTP is valid for 5 min.)</td></tr>
```

Full Body:

```
    <form name="OnlineForm" method="post" onsubmit="return verify();" autocomplete="off">
        <table class="visa_table" width="77%">               
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="mainHeading" colspan="3"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text_center">
                    <div class="pageHeading text_center">
                        Appointment OTP
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100%">
                    <table class="visa_table" width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold"><br>Generated OTP for application id is : 30AF06.  (This OTP is valid for 5 min.)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><br><br>                                      
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Home Page" onclick="location.href = 'index.html';" type="button"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE FORM=NAME:"OnlineForm" ATTR=CLASS:"visa_table"&&width:"100%" EXTRACT=TXT
SET id EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/id is : (\\w+)\\./)[1];")
```